# Array type deduction in a function template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, explicit-specialization

I have a template method as follows:-

```
template<typename T, int length>
void ProcessArray(T array[length]) { ... }
```

And then I have code using the above method:-

```
int numbers[10] = { ... };
ProcessArray<int, 10>(numbers);
```

My question is why do I have to specify the template arguments explicitly. Can't it be auto-deduced so that I can use as follows:-

```
ProcessArray(numbers); // without all the explicit type specification ceremony
```

I am sure I am missing something basic! Spare a hammer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't pass arrays by value. In a function parameter `T array[length]` is *exactly the same* as `T* array`. There is no length information available to be deduced.

If you want to take an array by value, you need something like `std::array`. Otherwise, you can take it by reference, which doesn't lose the size information:

```
template<typename T, int length>
void ProcessArray(T (&array)[length]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the correct argument type: arrays can only be passed by *reference*:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
void process_array(T (&arr)[N])
{
    // arr[1] = 9;
}

double foo[12];
process_array(foo); // fine
```